# unpleasant nonorthogonal featureTypes in google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If I set visibility to "on" for featureType "road", I get roads *and* city names.  At that point, if I set visibility to "off", the roads disappear but the city names remain!
If I set visibility to "on" for featureType "administrative", once again I get roads and city names.  And when I flip the visibility to "off", the city names disappear but the roads remain.

For elementType I've tried "all" as well as things like "labels" and "geometry", to no avail.

How can I cleanly toggle roads *alone*, and city names *alone*?

This is in Javascript, and I'm doing things like this:

```
map = new google.maps.Map();
map.setOptions({styles: [{featureType: 'road',
                          elementType: 'geometry',
                          stylers: [{visibility: 'on'}]}]});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, you need to set all the featureTypes together.  Setting just 'road', say, resets everything else (administrative, poi, transit...) to its default.

Answer (score 0):

```
styles: [
          {
            featureType: 'all',
            elementType: 'labels.text',
            stylers: [
              {
                visibility: 'on'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```